# Is it possible to create multiple build pipelines of similar type in Azure DevOps?

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-pipelines-build-task

Suppose we have 100 static websites of similar type. It will have similar build pipeline tasks. So instead of creating build and release pipelines one by one using visual designer, is there a way to automate it so that it will get created automatically?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do that via rest api, also, if all the pipelines are in different repos you can use azure-pipelines.yaml in the root of the repo, it will pick it up automatically.

go to builds > edit > top right >

[image]

on the next screen you can rename it:

[image]

Comment: Can you please explain in detail how we can do that using rest api? (or share a link).

Comment: Can we create release pipeline using YAML?

Comment: I cannot change the pipeline name when using yml file to configure the build pipeline in VSTS.
The default name is always <REPO_NAME>/<REPO_NAME> CI which is not ideal if we want to have separate build pipeline for different branches of a repository. Is it possible to change name?

Comment: yeah, why not? click edit build and gibe it a different name

Comment: I want to change name using Azure-pipelines.yaml only.

Comment: Edit build =>change name option not available. Yaml file is there

Comment: Got it. Thanks. Can it be changed using YAML? I have 25 similar websites with 4 environments each. I want to give different names to different environment build pipelines like. REPO_NAME-DEV-CI, REPO_NAME-PROD-CI

Comment: i think only using rest api, i'm not aware of how this can be configured from within yaml file, looking at the schema - it cant